# How to properly import a csv file to DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

**Goal**: My intention is to download data from yahoo finance into a pandas.DataFrame once a day and save it to a csv file. Then use this csv as a source throughout the day, thus (re-)loading it into a pandas.DataFrame.

**Issue**: When using the yahoo download dataframe I am able to access the values using `msft[msft.index[0]]` but when using the (re-)loaded dataframe and running `ms[ms.index[0]]` it throws a *KeyError: Timestamp('2006-01-04 00:00:00')*.

**Question**: Even though I browsed the internet for hours I was not able to overcome the issue. How can I access the data after (re-)importing the data?

---

**Code Snippet**
(Note: Yahoo Finance has changed its API had thus to find a work around to get it back running. I included it anyway to provide you a runnable example.)

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data #as pd_data_scraper
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override()


# Define the instruments to download
tickers = ['MSFT']

# We would like all available data from 'YYYY-MM-DD' until 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
start_date = '2006-01-03'
end_date = '2018-05-14'
data_source = 'yahoo'
group_by = 'ticker'

# User pandas_reader.data.DataReader to load the desired data
panel_data = data.get_data_yahoo(tickers, group_by=group_by)

# Getting just the adjusted closing prices. This will return a Pandas DataFrame
# The index in this DataFrame is the major index of the panel_data.
close = panel_data['Close']

# Getting all weekdays between 01/01/2000 and 12/31/2016
all_weekdays = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='B')

# How do we align the existing prices in adj_close with our new set of dates?
# All we need to do is reindex close using all_weekdays as the new index
close = close.reindex(all_weekdays)

# Reindexing will insert missing values (NaN) for the dates that were not present
# in the original set. To cope with this, we can fill the missing by replacing them
# with the latest available price for each instrument.
msft = close.fillna(method='ffill')

# save scraped data
file_path = '~/data/scraped_data'
current = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
data_path = os.path.join(file_path, current)
filename = os.path.join(data_path, 'data_dump_msft%s.csv' % current)
if not os.path.exists(data_path):
    os.makedirs(data_path)

# export to csv
msft.to_csv(filename)

ms_dir = '~/data/scraped_data/20180519/data_dump_msft20180519.csv'
ms = pd.read_csv(ms_dir, index_col=0, parse_dates=True) # setting from the former from_csv function

# the following should print twice the same but the second throws a KeyError instead
print('msft[msft.index[0]]: %s' % msft[msft.index[0]])
print('ms[ms.index[0]]: %s' % ms[ms.index[0]]) # KeyError: Timestamp('2006-01-04 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Please show a few rows of *msft* before exporting to csv and likewise *ms* after import from csv.

Answer (score 0):

`data_frame[something]` is accessing the column, use `iloc`, `loc` or `xs` for selecting rows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ryan Tam I came up with the following solution that produces wanted output:

`ms.xs(ms.index[0]).get_value(0)`